# Initializing array of objects

Tags: c++, arrays, class, object, initializing

I want to initialize an array. There's no compilation error but when I run the program it shows the first `cout` then stop running.

Here's my code:

```
class A {
    string first_name ;
    string last_name;
    int ID;
public:
    virtual void print ()=0;
};

class B :public A{
    string phone_number;

    .......
    void print(){
        ........
    }
};

class D{
    A** a;
    int size;
public:
    D(){
        size = 10;
        a = new A *[size];
        for(int i = 0 ; i<size ; i++){
            a[i] = NULL;
        }
    }

    void Add(){
        for(int i = 0 ; i<size ; i++){
            A * a2 = a[i];
            B * b  = dynamic_cast<B*>(a2);
            int id;
            cout<<"enter the id";
            cin>>id
            b->set_ID(id);
            // i did the same (cout , cin statements) for the first name and last name.
            b->set_first_name();
            b->last_name();
        }
};
```

Is this not correct?

Comment: You mean it prints "enter the id" and then after you enter an ID it doesn't continue?

Comment: All of the pointers in `a` are uninitialized when you initialize `a2` with them.

Comment: Your
formatting
/
indentation
could
use
some
work.

Comment: @sftrabbit Yes  , i did the cout and cin for the others (first name , last name ) but it didn't show up , and the program stop running

Comment: You do know about [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)?

Comment: Please format your code properly in the future. It’s not acceptable to write code without formatting, much less post it like that on here.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg  no , i don't know it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You allocate `size` amount of `A*`s, but you don't actually make those pointers point anywhere. <s>They're uninitialized.</s> Edit: now you're just setting them to NULL. You would need to allocate some `A` objects and assign their addresses to each of the elements of `a`. However, I see no good reason for you to be dynamically allocating the array of pointers - why don't you just declare `a` as `A* a[10];`? (or better yet, use a `std::vector` or `std::array`)

Comment: I use the dynamically allocating because of the phone_number , i couldn't reach it without dynamically allocating !

Comment: @RaiOu It looks more like you use dynamic allocation because you don't know how to use standard library containers.

Comment: Just a side remark : he never deallocate his `A` objects. That's a problem when allocating objects, it's easy to forget to deallocate them.

Comment: @GabrielL. that would lead to undefined behaviour, because `A` has no virtual destructor :-)